# GoToAsync Causes ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

Im creating a .NET MAUI app and following along with a guide on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddmZ6k1GIkM&t=406s) but altering what the app shows, but the functionality is mostly the same.

When I add navigation to a page and execute that code to go to the new page, I get ArgumentOutOfRangeException and the break mode screen comes up in Visual Studio 2022.

Im using the MVVM community toolkit version 8.1 (latest).
Im not passing any values from page A to new page B (I will once I sort this error out).

My ViewModel for page A contains a `[RelayCommand]` bound to a button on my UI (this is working fine) but at the end of this `[RelayCommand]` there is a call to a method which then takes you to the next page (intentionally, as there is no need for user input at this point so I want a different page to come up by itself).

That `[RelayCommand]` does some calculation then calls `GoToInfoPage()`, this is not marked `[RelayCommand]` as it doesnt need to be bound to anything on the UI.

`GoToInfoPage()` is below

```
async Task GoToInfoPage()
{
 await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(InfoPage));
}
```

The XAML on the InfoPage is simple right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:People.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:InfoPageViewModel"
             x:Class="People.Views.InfoPage"
             Title="InfoPage">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="InfoPage screen" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Its code behind is:

```
public partial class InfoPage : ContentPage
{
    public InfoPage(InfoPageViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

The view and VM are registered in `MauiProgram.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<InfoPage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<InfoPageViewModel>();
```

The route is registered in `AppShell.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(InfoPage), typeof(InfoPage));
    }
}
```

The ViewModel for InfoPage is:

```
public partial class InfoPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public InfoPageViewModel()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

My `AppShell.xaml` is below, the page im navigating to is not going to part of the main nav of the app and will only be displayed at certain times:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="People.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:People.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
    <ShellContent Title="Home"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}" 
            Icon="{OnPlatform Android='icon1.png', iOS='icon1.png', MacCatalyst='icon1.png'}"/>
</Shell>
```

The error is shown here too (there is no parameter 'index' that im using so must be part of the framework as it says)
[image]

What am I doing wrong here for this error to come up? Any help really appreciated

Comment: Could you switch the registration of the services. First ViewModel then view

Comment: @TheTanic I gave it a go but still getting the same error

Comment: I'm getting this same error.  But my code has been working for a couple months and just stopped working when I tested in Dark Mode.  Testing in Dark Mode was the first time it appeared (though I'd tested in Dark Mode previously) and going back to Light Mode did not fix it.  So, odd, but maybe unrelated.  Now, it just fails every time for this instance of the GoToAsync() call while all others in the project continue to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I solved it. Thanks to those who answered/commented to help.

Basically a rookie mistake in the end though. It didnt help that the Break Mode screen came up, but hope it helps someone else in future

My `[RelayCommand]` executes a method which does something, then moves the user to a new page.

What I didnt realise was after the user is moved to the new page, any remaining code still gets executed on the previous page, I assumed that any processing of further code on the previous page would stop as soon as the user was navigated to the new one. So, all I needed to do was put a `return;` **after** the `Shell.Current.GoToAsync()` and it solved the issue

Comment: In my instance, there is no code after the GoToAsync().  It invokes it within the [RelayCommand] and then just falls out of the [RelayCommand].

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the Visible property inside the ShellPage? I'm right? Please add shell page here
I think you have similar problems [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7417)

[Update answer]

Try change your Shell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <Shell
     x:Class="People.AppShell"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:views="clr-namespace:People.Views"
     Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
   
      <TabBar>
         <Tab x:Name="Home">
             <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}" Route="MainPage"/>
         </Tab>       
     </TabBar> </Shell>


public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(InfoPage), typeof(InfoPage));
        this.Home.Icon = "icon1.png";
    }
}
```

Method update too

```
async Task GoToInfoPage()
{
  await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}/{nameof(InfoPage)}");
}
```

Comment: ive added AppShell.xaml, im not using the Visible property

Comment: i gave this a go but did not work

Comment: Can you link your project?